# What is the alternative for magento registry?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Magento registry has been deprecated since Magento V2.3+, what is the new alternative for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,alternative is available right now.

By using a simple get() and set() function to a class, you can pass to any where at same page. A good example is given by our Dear @[vinai](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/766/vinai) at his a module at github. https://github.com/Vinai/module-current-product-example

The class: https://github.com/Vinai/module-current-product-example/blob/master/Registry/CurrentProduct.php#L8

Comment: nice explanation. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact use case, so I'll give an example for product only.

What you can do is check if the request has any parameters. If you're dealing with a product page for example, you could get the entity id of the product and then load it via the repository class.

Product page example:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Your\Namespace;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class ExampleClass
{
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    private $request;
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(RequestInterface $request, ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function loadProduct(): ProductInterface
    {
        // Verfify if your're dealing with a product page first
        $entityId = $this->request->getParam('id');
        return $this->productRepository->getById($entityId);
    }
}
```

In a lot of cases this can be an alternative to the older registry method to fetch the current product.